# In ASP.NET Core 5, How to create a list of strings which can be accessed within all web requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

My problem is that I do not understand where and what I should even be researching i.e. what search words/terminology I should use or what aspects of ASP.NET Core should I be researching. Yes, I confirm my knowledge of Core is very limited, and I have been reading thru docs, but no success so far.

**This is what I want to achieve:**

Before my web site can process any incoming HTTP requests (on app start), I would like to build a list of strings (key, value) in an array/object. The strings are read from a SQL table, and the list could contain 10,000 to 20,000 items (key,value). These strings will not change, hence I feel it is better to keep them in memory (pre-load in memory when web server starts/app starts).

**Importantly, I want to keep ONE copy of this list/dictionary in (each) web server instance, and I would like each incoming HTTP request to be able to access this list of strings (read-only, no changes will be made to strings) i.e. I want this list of strings to be shared across all HTTP requests.
I do not know, if this is possible, and if yes, then what exactly I should search for.
Could you please tell me what the solution can be or what I should research?**

Comment: Look at `MemoryCache`.  You can also use static class members, but cache object is most appropriate.

Comment: If I clearly understand what you are trying to do, you just want to create a list(Dictionary)  that is accessible to all your controller and you want to be able to populate it on project start. Am I right?

Comment: As for the correct terms, there are three basic approaches to solving this: **Caching services** (such as the `MemoryCache` class referenced above), **static properties** (which persist data independent of any instance), and **singleton lifestyles** (in which a single instance is made accessible via dependency injection, as discussed in @apocalypse's answer below). Caching services are really useful if you want .NET to manage the memory and evict stale items. Static properties are the simplest to implement, but tightly couple your code. The singleton lifestyle helps mitigate that last issue.

Comment: Hi Gnatt,  I would like to create a large list of strings which is loaded/created once, and then ALL accesses/HTTP connections should have read-only access to this list.  So, the entire app, all connections to that web server from all users, all controllers will have have access to this list of strings.

Comment: Thank you apocalypse/Jermey for the solution & explanation.

Can I not just load the data in the middle tier/singleton, and access it in app?  If I need to change the list I just change it in one place.  Why/How would such a method prevent testing?

In my mind, when we design/build/test something we can/should assume that the environment for it exists.  e.g. a jet engine test assumes oxygen is available (environment).

So, can test of a code function not assume that list of strings is there?  Why inject it in every controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create interface:

```
public interface IMyStaticData
{
    IReadOnlyList<string> GetData();
}
```

Create implementation:

```
public class MyStaticDataFromDatabase : IMyStaticData
{
    IReadOnlyList<string> data = null;
    readonly object sync = new object();

    public IReadOnlyList<string> GetData()
    {
        if (data != null) return data;

        lock (sync)
        {
             if (data != null) return data;
             data = // get data from database
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Register interface as singleton in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyStaticData, MyStaticDataFromDatabase>();
```

User this interface in controllers / razor pages etc.

Data will be loaded from database on first use. If you want to execute `GetData()` at app startup, you need to add code similar to this:

```
using IServiceScope serviceScope = app
.ApplicationServices
.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
.CreateScope()
{
    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyStaticData>().GetData();
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there are other, simpler approaches to achieving this—such as `static` properties, or registering a type without a corresponding `interface`. But @apocalypse's code introduces some slight complexity in order to maintain best practices that will prevent a lot of headaches down the road. For instance, with this approach it is possible to swap out a test double if you implement unit testing, or even another data providers should you later decide to use a different persistence store. It also includes basic concurrency checks to avoid conflicts when loading data. Good answer.